# jQuery InnerFade error in firefox

Tags: jquery

I hope one of you can help me, im using jQuery Innerfade on a website wich works and looks great but in FireFox when the page tab is inactive and i return after a couple of minutes it looks like innerfade needs to catch up with lost time.

This makes the slideshow go extremely fast for a 20/30 seconds before returning to normal. IE doesn't create this problem.

Does anyone know the solution the prevent this?

I've tried to pause the innerfade script on window blur but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, then i used this file of jquery: jquery-1.4.3.min.js

Worked out fine for me, hope this helps...